# OAuth2 service to service authorization

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

We are building two separate REST services and are looking for a way to let them securely communicate with each other.

If we can esstablish a secure communication between service A and B we can reverse the impl. and will be able to communicate from B to A.

We thought about using OAuth2 for this but find little or no information on how you could implement service to service authorization with OAuth2.

We have questions like what kind of grant type to use in such a scenario.

The idea we have now is, creating an account for server A on server B so server A can authenticate itself at server B and initialize the `client credentials` grant type flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea sounds okay. When Service A is a server, Service B is a client, and vice versa.